# activeNetworkInfo must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin, connection

I Make function to check internet connection in Base Activity so i can call this function in all my activity with simple code, but when i call this function, i get error "cm.activeNetworkInfo must not be null"

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var snackbar:Snackbar

    // call this method to show Snackbar in Activity
    fun showMessage(message: String?) {
        message?.let {
            snackbar = Snackbar.make(
                findViewById<View>(android.R.id.content),
                message, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
            )
            snackbar.show()
        }
    }

    fun checkConnection() : Boolean {
        val cm =  applicationContext.getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        val activeNetwork: NetworkInfo = cm.activeNetworkInfo
       return activeNetwork.isConnected

    }

    override fun onKeyDown(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        return when (keyCode) {
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME -> { true }
            KeyEvent.KEYCODE_APP_SWITCH -> { true }
            else -> { super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event) }
        }
    }


}
```

this is an error I got
[image: error cm connection]

Comment: have you tried removing applicationContext? and just calling getSystemService ?

Comment: I already did that, but i get some error

Comment: add that error to your question please